# How to concat 2 aac files using ffmpeg with delay between?

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to concat 2 aac files:

```
ffmpeg  -i 2.aac -i 3.aac  -filter_complex "[0]asetpts=0;[1]asetpts=8000; concat=n=2:a=0:a=1 [aout]" -map "[aout]" out.aac
```

first to 0 second, second to 8's second

I got the following error:

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_concat_2
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg -i 2.aac -i 3.aac -i 4.aac -filter_complex "[0]adelay=0[a0];[1]adelay=2000[a1];[2]adelay=1000[a2];[a0][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3" out.aac